# How do I turn VSCode Word Wrap off as default?

Tags: visual-studio-code, default, word-wrap

VS Code Version 1.36.1 for Mac.

Every time when I open VSCode, the word wrap is on. I have to ⌥+Z to turn it off. Whenever I close VSCode and reopen it, I have to do this again.

While in the Settings, either in User or Workspace, Editor: Word Wrap is `off`.

What am I doing it wrong? How to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try checking your configuration file.

**Windows:** `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`

**Mac:** `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`

**Linux:** `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`

And remove the parameter `"editor.wordWrap": "on"` or change it to `"editor.wordWrap": "off"`.

Comment: It doesn't have that. Only lines that have `editor.` are:

    `"editor.codeLens": true,`
    `"editor.minimap.enabled": false,`
    `"editor.fontSize": 13,`
    `"editor.fontLigatures": true,`
    `"[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },`

Comment: Maybe you've installed an extension that's causing this problem?

Comment: and one more line:
    `"editor.fontFamily": "Menlo, Monaco, 'Courier New', Fira Code, monospace"`

Comment: I have installed markdown related extensions: "Markdown Table Prettifier", and "Excel to Markdown table".

Answer (score 1):

I still encountered this issue in v1.64.2 on MacOS. I found a workaround in [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/60021#issuecomment-428529660) Github thread answer. Setting or adding accessibility option to "on" worked for me.

```
"editor.accessibilitySupport": "on"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. This is an unexpected workaround.

Comment: Warning: this solution unfortunately didn't solve the problem for me, but made VSCode emit sound whenever I edited Markdown files. I was incredibly frustrated until I finally identified the culprit.

Answer (score -1):

There is a fringe case where explicit `word-wrap: off` doesn't work. All you have to do to fix it is this:

<kbd>Alt + z</kbd> / <kbd>Option + z</kbd>

Do this in the editor that is wrapping lines.

---

***More info:***

This occurs most commonly when you paste a long line from one file to another.

Pressing <kbd>Alt + z</kbd> will force the viewport to update the horizontal virtualization (or lack thereof). You can read more about this bug-that's-not-a-bug here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/21124#issuecomment-308644030